# Connect to Non Domain Sql Server 2014 with Sharepoint 2013 installed on domain?

Tags: config-database

1. I have installed SQL server 2014 on new server.
2. I have installed SP 2013 on new server with Active Directory and Domain Controller.

Now while running the SP Configuration Wizard, how do I connect to the Database from SP server. how to set the credentials for the database settings.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good idea, because you will see tons of issue with this type of topology. I would highly recommend to join the SQL server to the domain and then cofnigure your farm. Another thing, SharePoint installation on the domain controler also not supported.

if your SharePoint servers are on Domain but SQL server is non-domain but available on the network then you can use SQL Authentication to connect the SQL server. But again their are limitation in this type, you cannot use the User Profile Sync services.

You have to manually run the Config wizard 1st via command line then from GUI. here are commands for it.

```
    PSConfig -cmd -configdb -create -server database_servername -database SharePoint_Config -user domain/username -password password 
-dbuser sharepoint_login_username -dbpassword sharepoint_login_password -admincontentdatabase SharePoint_AdminContent
```

The arguments for:

server - this would be your SQL Database Server's Instance name

database - the database name for SharePoint's configuration (we name it SharePoint_Config here)

user - the windows account used as the server farm's administrator account

dbuser - the SQL login account to connect to the database

admincontentdatabase - the database name for SharePoint's Central Administration site (SharePoint_AdminContent)